# Flow typed don't statically type object property types

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, static-typing

I have an object that contains different properties that are statically typed. The issue is when I try to access one of those properties statically, flow doesn't seem to understand and return the type for the specific property that I wanna access.

Is it a flow limitation or do there is a way to handle that ?

Here's a sample code that showcase what I want to achieve

```
/* @flow */
const object = (({
  first: 'first',
  second: 2,
}): {
  first: string,
  second: number
});

type ObjectPropertiesType = $Keys<typeof object>;

const getObjectValue = (property: ObjectPropertiesType) => {
  if (!object[property]) throw new Error(`object.${property} not exisiting`);

  return object[property];
};

// -> Flow here complains that getObjectValue isn't compatible with string but is string | number
const getFirst = (): string => getObjectValue('first');
```

[See it in action in flow type repl](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5hwBGAVgKboEC8YAFLQN6phhQCWATvgFxgDk7Lnj4AaZmBwVsAE14AmMQF8AlLyYtBPCXg5ssAczEtJmLLLBYArgFsiZDqhUBuVKjwBPAA5kwAeVIUeAAKHHDeHHhsZDgAKl4+NAAkANJk7jgAPB7ecFCEAZQAfC4Y2Phg+mR4-uSUAGoAhjCWCXSeoeEevDWBIWH2kdFx3spgVIVg6mBsebQAhMS1eADa7f0R7gC6o3gAFqFIWGRIAKIcoRy0AAaLgQB0iQxrne6KFnAEZAAebDhskQYrsoSiwOFVLBwsPklqsOgMti5FCVTOVKngAGKcco0WiqbS6AxjCZonr1JotWgCLHCYFAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the question answered on the github flow repo https://github.com/flowtype/flow-bin/issues/112

Here's the solution :

```
/* @flow */
const object = (({
  first: 'first',
  second: 2,
}): {
  first: string,
  second: number
});

type ObjectPropertiesType = $Keys<typeof object>;

type GetValueType = <Prop: string>(property: Prop) => $ElementType<typeof object, Prop>;

const getObjectValue: GetValueType = (property) => {
  return object[property];
};

const getFirst = (): string => getObjectValue('first');
const getSecond = (): number => getObjectValue('second');
const getSecondWrong = (): string => getObjectValue('second');
const getWrong = (): string => getObjectValue('third');
```

[See it in action](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5hwBGAVgKboEC8YAFLQN6phhQCWATvgFxgDk7Lnj4AaZmBwVsAE14AmMQF8AlLyYtBPCXg5ssAczEtJmLLLBYArgFsiZDqhUBuVKjwBPAA5kwAeVIUeAAKHHDeHHhsZDgAKl4+NAAkANJk7jgAPB7ecFCEAZQAfC5u8WAA4mR4AGoAhjCWZHHeYDQZIWG8+LoGhbSeoeEevB2eyq2FYIkAojBk1mRYeM1kWfG5+eSUImCjxa6m+GD6Vf5bNfWNvJUXDU1lNP2D9h7jVJPqYBxVlhxYm4EANoDMIvdwAXRcihKhwIJzwADFOEdHqptD19BNjqcCrdGrQBMjhMoXLDsXgAMpSMytOhoqy2exY+FnQJ1O4EkwyPgkjDYI7wqmmaQAdVCBlptDR3T0mPe5NZlHZ+L4XLMPNJ-LhVTF2DldK6OllzJx52VZAJeAAFpxpBqgA)